# Blogger vs AdSense pageview discrepency

Tags: blogger, adsense

**Last 30 days of my Blogger history:**

[image: Last 30 days of my Blogger history]

**Last 30 days of AdSense History for my Blogger:**

[image: Last 30 days of AdSense History for my Blogger]

## Question

Is there a reason these are so different? I'm not a big-time blogger by any means, but this seems to be very different.

I don't count my own pageviews, so this begs the question -- is AdSense knocking my pageviews down for some reason?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdSense has stricter requirements to count a view as a view than blogger. It also only counts "Ad Views" for the first ad on page (impressions are for all ads). Your users also could have ad blockers enabled, which would affect the ad count.

Check this out for more information: http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55613

Comment: Thanks! Helpful, to the point, and linked to more info.